# Can anyone please suggest the things which are bad with this SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query

I saw this query somewhere as a bad example which took their application down.

```
select oldurl, 
       newurl, 
       id, 
       dateadd 
from  jos_sh404sef_urls 
where newurl <> ""  
AND oldurl not like '%vmchk%' 
AND newurl not like '%format=feed%' 
AND newurl not like '%format=pdf%' 
AND newurl not like '%print=1%' 
AND oldurl not like '%__404__%' 
AND (  soundex(oldurl) = soundex('not_found') OR  oldurl like '%not%' OR  oldurl like '%found%') 
GROUP BY oldurl limit 500;
```

The only thing I can recognize is the multiple wildcard match. What are the other things here considered bad practice or antipattern or just bad.

Comment: For detailed answer please post, table description, execution plan and some data example. With the given info I can tell that no index if present on columns `newurl`,`oldurl` will be used. Still if you use [NOT MATCH AGAINST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973214/negation-with-match-against)   the fulltext index if present wont be used.

Comment: How many rows are in `jos_sh404sef_urls`?  What do you mean by "take down"?  The query will be slow, but will not crash the system.

Answer (score 3):

Some things that *can* degrade query performance, used in your example:

1. The multiple *leading* wildcards are not [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and therefore can't utilize a regular B-Tree index for efficient searching.
2. `NOT` operators such as `<>` and `NOT LIKE` are also not sargable, and will likely result in a full table / index scan.
3. Using functions in predicates (`JOIN` and `WHERE`) clauses *can* also be non-sargable or add measurable overhead in cases when they are sargable. In your example query, the `soundex()` function is used multiple times in the `WHERE` clause.
4. Multiple `OR` clauses in a predicate also complicate the predicate for the SQL Engine, and *can* lead to a poorer query plan being chosen too. Usually rewriting the query to use the `UNION` clause instead, is a more performant implementation.

With all of that being said, just because each of those things *can* cause performance problems, doesn't mean they all are for the given query. Every query is different, and these things won't always degrade performance, it just depends. The only way to actually know what the main bottlenecks are is by looking at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to review the query plan of the query itself.